# How to clean existing properties and replace with metadata template on Photoshop (scripting)?

Tags: scripting, photoshop, jsx, photoshop-script

While creating a script that would automate all the different tasks I do when I start working on a new picture on Photoshop, I encountered the following problem.

Manually, I would <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>, click on the template I want and choose the option "Clear existing properties and replace with template properties".

I can't find the way to do precisely this. The best thing I managed to find is something like this :

```
app.activeDocument.info.author = "test";
app.activeDocument.info.caption = ""; 
app.activeDocument.info.captionWriter = "";
app.activeDocument.info.headline = "";
app.activeDocument.info.instructions = "";
app.activeDocument.info.keywords = "";
app.activeDocument.info.authorPosition = "";
app.activeDocument.info.credit = "";
app.activeDocument.info.source = "";
app.activeDocument.info.category = "";
app.activeDocument.info.supplementalCategories = "";
app.activeDocument.info.title = "";
// etc.
```

And it actually doesn't really work like the "Clear existing properties and replace with template properties".

I didn't find anything on the Photoshop scripting guide, nor on the internet. Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

What I think is the problem is Photoshop separates file-metadata from its activeDocument-metadata. What you see in "File info..." (via Ctrl+Alt+Shift+I) is supposed to represent the file in the filesystem, which metadata is embedded in.

There are several scripting guides to Photoshop scripting. I think the one relevant for you would be "[Javascript Tools Guide](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/scripting/pdfs/javascript_tools_guide.pdf)", specifically the chapter 10 "[Scripting Access to XMP Metadata](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/scripting/pdfs/javascript_tools_guide.pdf#page=257)".

Is it important for you to set up the metadata already when creating a new picture? If not, you may want to look at a solution using [a customized export script](https://github.com/fredrikku/Photoshop-Export-Layers-to-Files-Fast).

It customizes XMP-metadata upon exporting like

*Create a basic metadata object:*

```
var meta = new XMPMeta();
```

*Provide a namespaceURI (see [XMP](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/xmp.html) [specs](https://wwwimages2.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/xmp/pdfs/XMP%20SDK%20Release%20cc-2016-08/XMPSpecificationPart1.pdf#page=13)) known to photoshop along with tag name, and value:*

```
meta.setProperty(XMPConst.NS_XMP, "CreatorTool", app.version);
```

*Save the image temporarily (using other script):*

```
var imgFile = new File(fileName); 
saveImage(fileName);
```

*Finish saving by adding the metadata-object:*

```
 var metaFile = new XMPFile(imgFile.fsName, XMPConst.FILE_UNKNOWN, XMPConst.OPEN_FOR_UPDATE); 
 if (metaFile.canPutXMP(meta)) { metaFile.putXMP(meta); }
 metaFile.closeFile(XMPConst.CLOSE_UPDATE_SAFELY);
```

Doing it this way also erases any existing or default metadata.